# LIB JailMonkey on react native app. error : [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'JailMonkey.hookDetected')]

Tags: android, react-native, jailbreak

Already try manual link, my rn version is "react-native": "0.63.4", "jail-monkey": "^2.6.0".

```html
import JailMonkey from 'jail-monkey';

useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const a = await JailMonkey.hookDetected()
            alert(a)
            setIsDevelopmentSettingsMode(a)
        })();
      }, []);
```

[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'JailMonkey.hookDetected')]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved.

I identify the problem was rn version, I was using version 0.63.3 with expo. the lib only works with rn version 0.64, even 0.65 doesn't work.